# Monte Carlo tree search - handling game ending nodes

Tags: artificial-intelligence, monte-carlo-tree-search

I have implemented a MCTS for a 4 player game which is working well, but I'm not sure I understand expansion when the game ending move is in the actual Tree rather than in the rollout.

At the start the game game winning/losing positions are only found in the rollout and I understand how to score these and propagate them back up the tree.  But as the game progresses, I eventually find a leaf node, chosen by UCB1 that cannot be expanded as it is a losing position with no possible move allowed, so there is nothing to expand, nor is there a game to 'rollout'.  At the moment I just score this as a 'win' for the last remaining player and backpropagate a win for them.

However when I look at the visit stats this node gets revisited thousands of time, so obviously UCB1 'chooses' to visit this node many times, but really this is a bit of a waste, should I be back-propagating something other than a single win for these 'always win' nodes?

I've had a good Google search for this and cant really find much mention of it, so am I misunderstanding something or missing something obvious, none of the 'standard' MCTS tutorials/algorithms even mention game ending nodes in the tree as special cases, so I'm worried I've misunderstood something fundamental.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> At the moment I just score this as a 'win' for the last remaining player and backpropagate a win for them.
>
> However when I look at the visit stats this node gets revisited thousands of time, so obviously UCB1 'chooses' to visit this node many times, but really this is a bit of a waste, should I be back-propagating something other than a single win for these 'always win' nodes?

No, what you're currently already doing is correct.

MCTS essentially evaluates the value of a node as the average of the outcomes of all paths you have run through that node. In reality, we are generally interested in minimax-style evaluations.

For MCTS' average-based evaluations to become equal to minimax-evaluations in the limit (after an infinite amount of time), we rely on the Selection phase (e.g. UCB1) to send so many *simulations (= Selection + Play-out phases)* down the path(s) that would be optimal according to minimax evaluations that the average evaluations also tend, in the limit, to the minimax evaluations.

Suppose, for example, that there is a winning node **directly** below the root node. This is an extreme example of your situation, where the terminal node is already reached in the Selection phase, and no Play-out is required afterwards. The minimax evaluation of the root node would be a win, since we can directly get to a win in one step. This means we want the average-based scoring of MCTS to also become very close to a winning evaluation for the root node. This means that we want the Selection phase to send the vast majority of simulations immediately down into this node. If e.g. 99% of all simulations immediately go to this winning node from the root node, the average evaluation of the root node will also become very close to a win, and that's exactly what we need.

---

This answer is only about the implementation of basic UCT (MCTS with UCB1 for Selection). For more sophisticated modifications to that basic MCTS implementation related to the question, see [manlio's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50796917/monte-carlo-tree-search-handling-game-ending-nodes/50836480#50836480)

Answer (score 2):

> none of the 'standard' MCTS tutorials/algorithms even mention game ending nodes in the tree as special cases

There are MCTS variants able to prove the game theoretical value of a position.

MCTS-Solver is (quite) well known: the backpropagation and selection steps are modified for this variant, as well as the procedure for choosing the final move
to play.

Terminal win and loss positions occurring in the tree are handled differently and a special provision is taken when backing such proven values up the tree.

You can take a look at:

[Monte-Carlo Tree Search Solver](https://dke.maastrichtuniversity.nl/m.winands/documents/uctloa.pdf) by Mark H. M. Winands, Yngvi Björnsson, Jahn Takeshi Saito (part of the Lecture Notes in Computer Science book series volume 5131)

for details.

> so I'm worried I've misunderstood something fundamental.

Although in the long run MCTS equipped with the UCT formula is able to converge to the game-theoretical value, basic MCTS is unable to prove the game-theoretical value.